# Captar um clique em 3D no openGL

Tags: c, opengl

estou fazendo um trabalho em openGL. Queria clicar em uma janela e um desenho aparecer onde foi clicado. Como o cenario eh em 3D queria saber como faco para obter o valor da coordenada em Z.

Alguem poderia dizer um passo-a-passo de como fazer? =)

Comment: bem vinda ao *StackOvarflow*, seria interessante você colocar jundo da sua pergunda, um trecho do código que você já tem feito. Isso ajuda para dar uma resposta final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem diferentes técnicas para trabalhar com seleção de objetos em `OpenGL`. Conheço essas duas:

- Cada objeto na cena deve possuir um id em memória, quando você capturar o clique, você deve percorrer todos os objetos que estão sendo renderizados e verificar se há colisão entre a coordenada de clique e cada objeto. Você deverá aplicar a sua matriz de projeção, antes de verificar a colisão.
- Desenhar em um `buffer` separado, utilizando cores diferentes para cada objeto, ao receber o evento do clique, leia a cor do pixel naquela posição e consulte a cor em uma dicionário de `cores->objetos`

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que trabalhar sobre uma textura OpenGL da *viewport* que possa ser usada pelas funções OpenGL.

Então eu conheço 2 soluções:

1. Usar uma função que leia um pixel (`glReadPixel` se eu não me engano). Mas geralmente essa comunicação entre GPU e CPU é lenta.
2. Criar um código `glsl` que passa como uniformes as coordenadas do mouse e a textura (criada com o `glGenTextures`). O trabalho seria feito diretamente na GPU, então seria uma forma mais eficiente.